# Vb.net Itextsharp OCR Check

Tags: vb.net, itext

How do i check if a file is PDF OCR

Process

1. Select PDF file
2. Check PDF file if its file is PDF OCR
3. Message (True or False)

Comment: How do you abstractly intend to recognize OCR'ed pdfs? Based on that information we're may help you to implement it concretely using itext.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer using itextsharp (i am using 5.5.10.0)

```
   Public Sub CHeck(ByVal Filename As String, ByRef sOut As String) 
    Dim oReader As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(FileName)
    For i = 1 To oReader.NumberOfPages
        Dim its As New iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.SimpleTextExtractionStrategy
        sOut &= iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(oReader, i, its)
    Next
```

then just make a condition if the string is blank or not
this can also be looped by for each filename.

Comment: That code merely checks whether there are text showing operations in the page contents. How does that relate to OCR?

Comment: If the file contains parse text that means the file has been run through the OCR. for what i needed i only need to check if the document has been run through the OCR process not to check if every single page is OCR. that is why this code works for me.

i also just create a condition if sOut - "" then its not OCR else it is. mostly i create a loop for a specific directory.

Comment: Ok, so your pdfs all are scanned and only some of them are OCR'ed. According to your question, though, that was not clear and I had assumed you meant arbitrary pdfs.

Comment: yes, you select a PDF file. see if the file is OCR'ed. and return a value if it is OCR or not.

to me accurate when i say OCR the file has been processed by OCR and the text have been recognized. that is why parse text will give me info if it is OCR or not.